# Retrieve data according to timestamp value from Room Database

Tags: android-room

I'm trying to retrieve entries that were written in the last 2 minutes into the database.
I use the following query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Contacts where ('now()' - gatt_server_connection_timestamp) <= 120000")
    List<Contact> getContactsByGattServerConnectionTimestamp();
```

However the result I get is the whole database.

What is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite date-time functions are [described here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

If `gatt_server_connection_timestamp` is in milliseconds since epoch, this query should work:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Contacts where gatt_server_connection_timestamp >= (1000 * strftime('%s', datetime('now', '-2 minutes'))))
    List<Contact> getContactsByGattServerConnectionTimestamp();
```